# Do not understand formula...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does;

$x^{n} -y^{n}=(x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y+...+x y^{n-2}+ y^{n-1} )$

work on $x^{2} - y^{2}$

When I attempt to apply the formula on $x^{2} - y^{2}$

I get the following

$x^{2} - y^{2} =(x-y)( x^{1} + x^{0}y+...+x y^{0} + y^{1} )$

$x^{2} - y^{2} =(x-y)(2x+2y)$

which is obviously false. What is the correct way to use the formula?

Comment: Try rewriting it in the proper notation instead of dots.

Comment: wouldnt we then enter the  $x^{n-3}$ term, but how would that help?

Comment: You have to stop when the power of x becomes 0.

Comment: Thats what I've done ,haven't I?

Comment: Regarding your edit , that is an interesting question that should be asked separately , in a separate thread. First check to see if it has been asked and answered already. :)

Comment: It's fine I understand now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many terms, $x^{n-n}y^{n-1}$ is the last, which in this case is your second term $x^{n-2}y$. The third term would in your case be $x^{n-3}y^{n-2}$ which we don't want since $n=2$ and the exponent of $x$ would become negative.

To more easily see this, write the factorization in this form:

$$x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + \dots + x^{n-(n-1)}y^{n-2} + x^{n-n}y^{n-1})$$

In this case it becomes

$$x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^1y^0 + x^0y^1) = (x-y)(x + y)$$

which of course is the correct factorization.

Comment: Thanks, I found your 1st  equation very useful. I can see what you mean now.

Answer (score 4):

$$x^2 - y^2 = (x -y)(x^1y^0 + x^0y^1) =(x-y)(x+y)$$

Answer (score 4):

If you use proper notation, instead of dots, you get the correct result:

$x^n-y^n=(x-y)\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-k}y^k$

Then $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x^{1-0}y^0+x^{1-1}y^1)=(x-y)(x+y).$

Answer (score 2):

Note how the last term in the factorization of $x^n-y^n$ has $x$ raised to the $0$th power. That means you have to stop when $x$ is raised to the power of $0$.
$$x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x^1y^0+x^0y^1)$$
$$\boxed{x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)}$$